# Could you breed livestock with structurally colored wool?

Tags: science-based, biology, light, colors, hair

Imagine you have low magic, low tech nomads with a magical equivalent of microscopes, and a rudimentary understanding of genetics and optics (blame magic). They are selectively breeding livestock for nearly half a million years, and will covet any with unique wool.

There are two different ways I can imagine this maybe working, but perhaps you can think of others:

- Firstly you could have hollow hair with a central cavity, or a wall thickness just the right size to cause optical interference.
- Secondly you could have the scales on the hairs themselves in a spacing which causes optical interference.

**Is it actually plausible that you could get structural color evolving in mammals wool?**
If so, could it replicate anything structural coloration can do in birds? Or would structurally colored hair be limited in what optical effects and/or colors it could produce?

There should be no genetic engineering involved beyond selective breeding.

Comment: something is seriously wrong with me, I've been trying to coax a Angora rabbit to do something to a Chrysospalax golden mole since they are similar in size and you need wool right?

Comment: Maybe switch the [hard science] tag out for the [science based] one, people are going to find it hard to find actual research papers for any elements of this I feel, the best you can probably hope for is some Wikipedia links to illustrate some basics behind their reasoning I think, I could be wrong of course but the hard science tag doesn't seem necessary for this one to me.

Comment: @Pelinore - indeed. From hard science tag description: "For questions that require unequivocal proof that answers are correct through the use of equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, etc". Scientific papers are filed for peer review, they prove nothing and by their nature are in doubt. The only way to equivocally prove this breeding can be done is to actually do it.

Comment: You won't get the sharply defined patterns you get in peacocks feathers, hair (or wool) isn't held stiffly in place like a feathers individual filaments with their hooks so that's not going to be possible, particularly if you want usable wool, single colours and broad patterns (blue on the back with a cream belly and pink socks or whatever) should be doable, presuming you want to use wool as wool single colours make more sense with different breeds for each .. seems like a lot of work to avoid Dyeing though, which is better (more flexible) as same white wool can be used for any colour ;)

Comment: @Pelinore Realized hard science was asking a bit much and swapped it. The big advantage I was imagining to this having over just natural dyes is you would be able to do more colors and get iridescence maybe? Since the angle of viewing seems like it would matter for the first mechanism I proposed

Comment: @VakusDrake lacking any other method to reliably achieve it in clothing Iridescence could be the big draw certainly ;) and science type dudes (with magic tools or otherwise) are notorious for doing things just for the hell of it anyway ;) given viewed images of golden mole rats iridescence can be done.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no.

Some colors of butterfly wings are structural in nature, so this effect definitely can happen in nature.

The problem is, you want it to be wool. Structural coloration due to its nature deals very poorly with dust, oil, water, dirt, or mechanical force. Wool is rather dirty. So there is no evolutionary benefit for an animal to get structurally colored wool.

Also cloth takes a lot of physical punishment both in manufacturing and everyday usage. It is also often gets dirty and has to be washed with aggressive substances. Structural coloring is a neat idea but not particularly practical.

> They are selectively breeding livestock for nearly half a million years

This part is very suspicious TBH because it implies existence of relatively stable civilization which in half a million years didn't find a better way to manufacture colorful cloth.

*Homo sapiens* didn't exist as a species half a million years ago.

Comment: All answers to this question should be backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc. Answers that do not satisfy this requirement might be removed.

Comment: @L.Dutch - equations? In biology? "What if" question about peculiar mutations and selective breeding has to have equations? Good luck with that.

Comment: @L.Dutch - feel free to add any real criticism about the answer - mistakes or wrong assumptions. Also I very much want to know about the formulas which cover the question of selectively breeding species with wool with structural coloration. I didn't realize it was such a well researched area and burning with curiosity. Links please.

Comment: read the entire sentence, without stopping at the coma:  equations, **empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc.**

Comment: Here just throw these in, [structural coloration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_coloration), [selective breeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_breeding), all he wants is to change the physical shape of individual hair filaments making up wool, presuming his magic microscopes are strong enough to be able to see what they're doing it self evidently can be done in far less than the allotted time, we've made more significant changes to pigeons and other animals in far less.

Comment: *"to see what they're doing"* > strong enough to be able to see differences in width, shape and structure of individual filaments of hair (wool) in individual animals so they can selectively breed for the incremental changes required.

Comment: You might also note that the [Golden Mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_mole) is noted as having structurally coloured fur in that wikipedia link on structural colour, as evidence that it's definitely possible to have in the fur, hair and wool of mammals.

Comment: Here's a [science illustrated](https://scienceillustrated.com.au/blog/nature/scientists-identify-iridescence-in-golden-moles/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CThe%20structural%20characters%20of%20golden,various%20species%20to%20attract%20mates.) article that also mentions their structurally coloured fur to further confirm that.

Comment: Many ducks (including the familiar mallards) have structural coloration in a brightly coloured patch on their wing (the *speculum*) — and they live happily in muddy ponds and streams.  So some structural coloration can tolerate plenty of water and dirt, and at least a bit of mechanical force.

Comment: @all the "here are science paper" folks. The tag is changed from "hard science" to "science based" and it means: "For questions that require plausible (better than suspension-of-disbelief) answers based on Real World science that are not necessarily constrained to the known limits of Real World science. Contrast with the hard-science, science-fiction and internal-consistency tags". So, if you still want to "unequivocal prove" that it can be done with articles and formulas - you are very welcome to write your own answer. I can use some laugh.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine - so, did anyone made a cloth out of them? Remember, you need to "unequivocally prove" its possible.